# PHP and paths - relative to file and not including code

Tags: php

I am really confused about PHP and the path system.

I have this structure:

```
- Includes
- Login
- View
   * Secure
```

These are all directories on my site. Now, if i place files in the "View" folder, i can access files in my Includes folder with:

```
"../Includes/file.php"
```

If i want to include the same file from the Secure directory, i would do:

```
"../../Includes/file.php"
```

This is all fine, but here is where it gets tricky for me.

If the file i try to import (the file.php in the Includes directory) ALSO includes a file, it will throw everything off. Say that file will include a file in "Login", it would have to be ONE of these 2 includes, all depending on if the code that includes it is in the Secure or View directory:

```
"../Login/file.php" -> if it was included from the View directory
"../../Login/file.php" -> if it was included from the Secure directory.
```

Obviously this problem only gets worse and worse. Maybe what i am after, is a way to have the path be relative to the FILE itself, and NOT the including code?

On another note, i guess what i am really after is how to handle all this include "hell" in PHP? I feel that i bind my structure tightly together and that i can't change much without everything breaking. So any advise on how to handle this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of paths: relative, and absolute. Absolute paths start with a `/..` (or `C:/..` or however that works on Windows) and always unequivocally point at one specific file.

Relative paths (not starting with `/`) are relative to the `include_path` variable. That's a variable that contains a bunch of folders, where PHP will look for your relative path. That `include_path` also includes `.`, the *current* directory. The "current" directory depends on which file was the "first" to be executed. So it varies depending on which file starts to `include` others.

1. You can [set your `include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to some specific, unchanging directory, so you always have a fixed path to include to relatively.
2. **Better:** *construct* absolute paths:

   ```
   include __DIR__ . '/../Login/file.php';
   ```

   This is always relative to the directory the file is in.

Comment: So you would actually recommend constructing absolute paths, even though a clear drawback is the higher coupling between your files? Also, the __DIR__ is not a viable solution on its own, since it is not starting at the sites web directory, it goes further up - Besides, i assume you down voted my question due to the lack of formatting. I will correct this in the future. If there was another reason, let me know.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. :) The paths are either relative to a fixed root with setting the `include_path`, or relative to one another using `__DIR__`. Either way you'll have to edit a bunch of files if you ever change your directory structure. – To avoid that altogether you should use classes and autoloading; though that still means you'll edit a bunch of namespace names if you change the directory structure.

Comment: But don't the both pose a terrible environment for big projects? If i make it relative to the include_path, i would have to (as far as i understand) set the include_path for EACH script. If i later decide to change it, i need to go through every single file and change it.

Again, if i use __DIR__ there is a big problem in that it doesn't start at the website directory, it goes even further. For instance on localhost, the __DIR__ would be "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite" instead of just "mySite".

Comment: You would certainly not include `set_include_path` in every single file. You would either include it in the core `php.ini` or a PHP configuration directive in your Apache configuration for that specific site, or ideally you should have some common bootstrap file that all your requests go through anyway where you can do that. And yes, `__DIR__` refers to the directory of the file it's written in, so it's a defined starting point to write a relative path to. You'll have problems either way if you rename files, there's no way around that at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe what i am missing is the Bootstrap file. A file all my requests go through, so i can make some basic setup there. I will try to learn more of this. thank you.

Comment: Really, the modern methodology is: 1) OOP, 2) autoloaders, no manual `include` at all, 3) URL rewriting to a bootstrap file with a router. Look at some popular frameworks that are based on this, e.g. Symfony.